# POST through SoapUI is unsuccessful, but the same request through DHC is completed successfully

Tags: rest, post, soapui, dhc

I tested REST services with DHC application for Chrome, and POST requests were successful with these parameters:
[DHC_successful_POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwF86.png)

But when I try to create the same request in SoapUI, I always get 500 error. Probably, there should be some other parameters or settings in SoapUI, but I cannot see it. What is wrong? Here is my request:
[SoapUI_POST_500_fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXOuY.png)

P.S.
In DHC there is such code for my request:

curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
   -F "file=" \
   -F "fileName=rich-text.zip" \

So, I just need to find settings for these parameters in SoapUI (free version).
Are there any suggestions?

Comment: You should be able to check the difference by comparing the two raw request. By the way, the information available in the question is inadequate.

Comment: Thank you!
In DHC raw request I see:

'POST /rest/templates HTTP/1.1
Host: _localhost:port_
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=------FormBoundary152c161cca2
Content-Length: 263

------FormBoundary152c161cca2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream'


------FormBoundary152c161cca2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

rich-text.zip
------FormBoundary152c161cca2--

But in SoapUI it is different, you are right. I need to post it through SoapUI as "form", but I can't find this option in the SoapUI

Comment: Did you try `http request` test step type?

Comment: Yes, I used HTTP step as well as REST, but it didn't help, result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/working-with-rest-requests.html) (see attachments section)you've to append `file:` to your parameter value to be able to send the content of file as `multipart/form-data`